# CRM 2011 RU13 Pending email warning causes chrome to hang

Tags: email, google-chrome, dynamics-crm-2011

How do I turn off the Pending email warning?

In fact how do I turn off all pop-up reminders in CRM 2011 RU13?

To recreate.

- Create an email and save it (direction must be Outgoing) .  Wait a few days (If you know how to
- trigger it earlier tell me).  Check in IE that you get the pending
- email message. Open the CRM in chrome...note that it fails Go back to
- IE Activities -> emails -> pending emails and delete the emails there
- Open the CRM in Chrome and rejoice.

I guess my current workaround would be a workflow that finds emails like this:

> *Direction Equals 'Outgoing' **AND** (Status Reason Equals 'Pending Send;Sending' **AND** Activity Status Equals 'Completed' **OR** Status Reason Equals 'Failed' **AND** Activity Status Equals 'Open')*

and kills them which is really bad.

**EDIT:**

Yes, it is the latest version of chrome.

**TO BE CLEAR**

I want to turn the popup reminders off in CRM. I have no control over the way people configure their browsers. I should, however, be able to configure CRM but, as seems so often the case, I can't.

Popups and Dialogs break the web. Just look at this site (stackoverflow), plenty of notifications and ways of collecting user input without a sniff of a popup message/dialog.

People turn popup blockers on because they represent a security risk. So this, IMHO, is an awful "Feature".

**EDIT 2**

And even if you needed to add popups, why would you make them blocking? I assume this is why chrome hangs.

Comment: did you check that they are using the latest version of google chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling pop-ups in Chrome for your CRM site. Worked for me.

Comment: I don't have any extensions that block popups and I added a rule to allow popups from my CRM...this didn't work. And asking users to do this is not the best solution as most of them can bare identify the difference between a keyboard and a mouse.

Answer (score 1):

You may be fixing the wrong problem. 
"Pending send" emails tell you that something is wrong.

Saving a new email (a draft, if you like) does not cause this. A user or workflow or marketing campaign can create emails all day long and not send them, and you will not see this warning message (the emails simply appear as activities to be done in your "to-do" list)

An email is "pending send" only if you send en email from CRM 'from' a user configured to use Outlook for outgoing mail but not logged on to Outlook for a while, or via email router but that is mis-configured (eg no credentials for that user) or not running. Figure out why the emails are "pending" and fix this issue, then your Chrome problem will vanish.

Comment: You are right Adam, but my question is about turning popups OFF. See Edit.